# H264 IP core encoder estimated cost

Tags: fpga

I would like to get an idea of what the licensing models for IP cores are (flat or per device?), and how much approximately an h264 encoder core could cost.

I see that other similar but more vague questions weren't closed, so I hope this one to be appropriate.

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. Question should be closed.

Comment: Please point out to us the other more vague questions that you saw.  We'll see if we can close those too.

Comment: What a badass you are. I'm sure that you have heard of this thing called search engines. Have fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Licensing they usually try for a large licensing fee plus royalties, then you negotiate from there.   Sometimes they'll give you a break on upfront cost if you agree to larger per chip royalties.   Upfront is usually always required since they need to provide you with support to get going.

Keep in mind just an h.264 encoder may not be all you need in your image processing pipeline.  As you start to add all the extras the price goes up.  Several years ago a syst that was useful to me was $500k but we were refusing to pay royalties.

I'd guess $100k - $200k now since the new thing to have is h.265 you may be able to get a deal.   Overseas providers are usually cheaper, and sometimes you can find a backend company that has the up already and you can roll it in a bit.   Also my experience has always been the less I pay for ip the bigger the promises and the worse the quality and support :)

Why not just call some ip companies and get their latest prices?  There's also a lot of h.264 chips out there already...

Comment: That's precisely what I was hoping to hear, it being orders of magnitude off my budget. Now I can go back playing with the mere mortal $10-$50 encoder chips, with my soul in peace :)

Thank you!